# Extract values from list and make tuples

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I need a simple thing but I cannot do it:

```
list = 'SBEDFG'
```

I need as output:

```
[(S,B),(B,E),(E,D),(D,F),(F,G)]
```

This is what I tried:

```
[(list[ind],list[ind+1]) for ind,i in list]
```

But it gives me this error:

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
>>> [(list[i-1], list[i]) for i in range(1, len(list))]
[('S', 'B'), ('B', 'E'), ('E', 'D'), ('D', 'F'), ('F', 'G')]
```

Comment: You were the first one and I wanted to see the solution with list comprehension so..thank you!

Comment: If this solve your problem, please select as answer and complete the workflow.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function like this:

```
>>>l = 'SBEDFG'
>>>zip(l,l[1:])
[('S', 'B'), ('B', 'E'), ('E', 'D'), ('D', 'F'), ('F', 'G')]
```

With Python 3.X you'll need to convert the `zip` result to a `list`:

```
#Python 3.X
>>>l = 'SBEDFG'
>>>list(zip(l,l[1:]))
[('S', 'B'), ('B', 'E'), ('E', 'D'), ('D', 'F'), ('F', 'G')]
```

With list comprehension I would do it with  `range()` function:

```
>>>[(l[i],l[i+1]) for i in range(len(l)-1)]
[('S', 'B'), ('B', 'E'), ('E', 'D'), ('D', 'F'), ('F', 'G')]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>>b=[]
>>> for ind,i in enumerate(list):
...  if ind < len(list)-1:
...   b.append((list[ind],list[ind+1]))
...
>>> print b
[('S', 'B'), ('B', 'E'), ('E', 'D'), ('D', 'F'), ('F', 'G')]
```